# How to fix window.open() in Heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to host a webpage on Heroku, using Node.js. Yes, I know about the php method, I want to do this with Node instead though. It's working really well so far actually, there's only one little problem.

My Procfile is as follows:
`web: node main.js`

My main.js file:
`window.open("index.html", "_self");`

My `index.html` file is fine and connects to the rest of it, but it's very long, so I don't really want to post it in here.

I have a `package.json` etc, but the following error pops up when I try to deploy the app.

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-12T03:23:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-09-12T03:23:24.424276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2018-09-12T03:23:26.694405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-12T03:23:26.710365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630643+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/main.js:1
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630664+00:00 app[web.1]: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { window.open("index.html", "_self");
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630666+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                               ^
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630668+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630670+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: window is not defined
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630671+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:1:63)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630672+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630674+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630676+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630677+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630679+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630680+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630682+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
2018-09-12T03:23:26.630684+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Obviously, this means that it doesn't recognize the "window", but I don't know how to fix this. If anyone has an answer, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, why you want to open index.html in the same window, rather than sending it with http response ? 

I think what you want to do is show your index.html file. If so, then please use http module to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running on Heroku, you're using NodeJS, not Javascript in the browser. There is no `window` in Node. So you can't use `window.open`.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

This will start a web server on port $PORT, or 5000 and serve the `index.html` file on all requests.
It should work as-is on Heroku.